# how to make login page in wordpress theme using php?

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

i am using AccessParallex Theme of wordpress, but i m not to create custom login page. Please tell me which file should be edited to make a login page in my webpage.

Answer (score 0):

creating constom template in login.php page then after wordpress creating page and call the page. 
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_user_reg where email='$usermail'" );
echo "ID"."  "."Name"."
";
foreach($result as $row)